# Unable to conditionally re render using react navigation in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, rtk-query

store.ts

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware, CaseReducer} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// import { loginUser } from './slices/auth';
// import { createStore } from 'redux';
// import loginScreen from './slices/auth';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { authApi, useLoginUserMutation } from './api/authApi';
import authSlice, { loginUser } from './slices/updatedAuth';
import auth, { loginUser as loginUser2 } from './slices/auth';
import { loginRequest } from '../types/auth';

export type type_1 = {
    initial: boolean,
    test: string
}

let initialCustomState: type_1 = {
    initial: false,
    test: "abc"
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ [authApi.reducerPath]: authApi.reducer});

// const store = configureStore({
//   reducer: { rootReducer },
//   middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
//     getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authApi.middleware)
// });

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        authSlice: authSlice
    },
    //  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    //  getDefaultMiddleware().concat(authApi.middleware),
})

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
// Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users: UsersState}
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export default store;
// store.dispatch(authApi.endpoints.loginUser({ email: "abc", password: "avc" }));
```

authslice.ts

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { loginRequest } from '../../types/auth';
import { authApi } from '../api/authApi';
import { TimeZone, user } from '../../types/user';

type authState = {
    authToken: string,
    userKey: string,
    user: user | null,
}

let initialState: authState = {
    authToken: '',
    userKey: '',
    user: null,
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'authInfo',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        loginUser: (state: authState, action: PayloadAction<loginRequest>) => {
            state.authToken = action.payload.email;
        },
        setUserDetails: (state: authState, action: PayloadAction<user>) => {
            state.authToken = action.payload.auth_token;
            state.userKey = action.payload.user_key;
            state.user = action.payload;
        },
        resetAuth: (state: authState, action: PayloadAction<void>) => {
            state.user = null;
            state.authToken = '';
        },
        setAuthToken : (state : authState, action : PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.authToken = action.payload;
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchPending, (state, action) => {
            console.log('pending', action);
            console.log(state);
        })
            .addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchFulfilled, (state, action) => {
                console.log('fulfilled', action);
                state.authToken = action.payload.auth_token;
                state.user = action.payload;
                state.userKey = action.payload.user_key;
                console.log("updated state" , state);

            })
            .addMatcher(authApi.endpoints.loginUser.matchRejected, (state, action) => {
                console.log('rejected', action);
            });
    },
});


export default authSlice.reducer;

export const { loginUser, setUserDetails, resetAuth, setAuthToken } = authSlice.actions;
```

stackNavigator.tsx

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('logged_in_user')
      console.log(jsonValue);
      return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
        
    } catch(e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  }




export default function StackNavigator() {
    let state = store.getState();
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    let [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    let [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(state.authSlice.authToken);
    let [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false);
    useEffect( () => {
      getData().then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if(res !== null) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setAuthToken(res.auth_token);
        dispatch(authSlice.actions.setAuthToken(res.auth_token));
        setIsSignedIn(true);
  
        } else {
            setIsLoading(false);
            setAuthToken('');
            setIsSignedIn(false);
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setAuthToken('');
        setIsSignedIn(false);
    })
    });

    if(isLoading) {
        return <FirstScreen></FirstScreen>
    } else {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator>
      <>
      {
        store.getState().authSlice.authToken !== '' ?
             <Stack.Screen name = "Drawer" component={DrawerNavigator} options = {{headerShown : false}}></Stack.Screen> :
             <>  
           <Stack.Screen name = "Login" component = {LoginScreen} options={{headerShown : false}} ></Stack.Screen>
         <Stack.Screen name = "ForgotPassword" component = {ForgotPasswordScreen} options = {{headerShown : false}}></Stack.Screen>
        </>
      }
         
      </>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
    }
}
```

App.tsx

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native'
import { createAppContainer, StackRouter } from 'react-navigation'
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItem, DrawerScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer, useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import useColorScheme from './hooks/useColorScheme';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import DrawerItems from './constants/DrawerItems';
import store from './src/redux/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import AccountScreen from './screens/AccountScreen';
import AlarmsScreen from './screens/AlarmsScreen';
import TasksScreen from './screens/TasksScreen';
import SupportScreen from './screens/SupportScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import Header  from './screens/Header';
import SafeAreaProvider  from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from './screens/ForgotPasswordScreen';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { authApi, useLoginUserMutation } from './src/redux/api/authApi';
import DrawerNavigator from './src/navigators/drawerNavigator';
import { authSlice } from './src/redux/slices/updatedAuth';
import StackNavigator  from './src/navigators/stackNavigator';




const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();


export default function App() {
  const state = store.getState();

  
  return (
 
       <NavigationContainer>
            <Provider store={store}>
      <StackNavigator></StackNavigator>
      </Provider>
  </NavigationContainer>
  
   
  );
}
```

LoginScreen.tsx

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { StyledButton, StyledTextInput, Logo, Header, Background, setDataInAsyncStorage} from '../src/utils/utils'
import {Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import { emailValidator } from './../src/validators/emailValidator';
import { passwordValidator } from './../src/validators/passwordValidator';
import { styles } from './../src/styles/styles';
import { Navigation } from '../src/types/genericTypes';
import { useLoginUserMutation } from '../src/redux/api/authApi';
import {Snackbar} from 'react-native-paper'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { authSlice, setAuthToken } from './../src/redux/slices/updatedAuth';
import { useAppDispatch } from './../src/redux/hooks';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getErrorMessageFromErrorListDTOResponse } from '../src/utils/utils';

type Props = {
  navigation : Navigation;
}

const LoginScreen = ({navigation} : Props) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState({value : '', error : ''});
  const [password, setPassword] = useState({value : '', error : ''});
  const [loginUser, {isLoading, isError}] = useLoginUserMutation();
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const onDismissSnackBar = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  }
  
  const _onLoginPressed = () => {
     const emailError = emailValidator(email.value);
     const passwordError = passwordValidator(password.value);
    
    

    if (emailError || passwordError) {
      setEmail({ ...email, error: emailError });
      setPassword({ ...password, error: passwordError });
      return;
    }
    var loginUserRequest = {
      email : email.value,
      password : password.value,
    };
    loginUser(loginUserRequest).unwrap().then((payload) =>  {
    setDataInAsyncStorage('logged_in_user', JSON.stringify(payload));
    dispatch(authSlice.actions.setAuthToken(payload.auth_token));
   }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error); 
    setError(getErrorMessageFromErrorListDTOResponse(error)); setVisible(true)});

    // navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
  };
  return (
    <Background>
        <Logo />

      <Header>Sign In</Header>
         <View>
      <StyledTextInput      
        label="Email"
        returnKeyType="next"
        value={email.value}
        onChangeText={text => setEmail({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!email.error}
        errorText={email.error}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        autoCompleteType="email"
        textContentType="emailAddress"
        keyboardType="email-address"></StyledTextInput>
      </View>
      <View>
          <StyledTextInput       label="Password"
        returnKeyType="done"
        value={password.value}
        onChangeText={text => setPassword({ value: text, error: '' })}
        error={!!password.error}
        errorText={password.error}
        secureTextEntry>

        </StyledTextInput>
        <Snackbar
        visible={visible}
        onDismiss={onDismissSnackBar}>
        {error}
      </Snackbar>
 
      </View>
      <View style={styles.forgotPassword}>
        <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("ForgotPassword")
        }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.forgotPasswordLabel}>Forgot your password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <StyledButton mode="outlined" onPress={_onLoginPressed} color = "#BAC8EF">
        Login
      </StyledButton>

      </Background>
  )
}

export default LoginScreen
```

I am relatively very new to using redux, react native, rtk query and central state management.
The problem I am facing is all the states are updating properly, but the app is not rerendering to display the proper current state that is the auth token despite getting updated is not redirecting to a new drawer screen navigator conditionally. It however does no action but works fine when refreshed

Answer (score 1):

You should not do something like

```js
    let state = store.getState();
    let [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState(state.authSlice.authToken);
```

ever.

Two things here:

- `useState` is for component-local React state and has nothing to do with Redux. Even if the state value would change, as the argument to `useState` only marks the *initial state*, the `authToken` will now never change again unless you call `setAuthToken`.
- you should never use `store.getState()` within a component.

Instead, do

```js
const authToken = useSelector(state => state.authSlice.authToken)
```